# 230V AC to 5V DC smart plug components

Tags: power-supply, identification

I've tried to find theory on how to convert 230V AC to 5V DC but without any good results.

I've been interested in how these wall plugs work and what the schematics are. Where can I read more about this?

What I'm trying to replicate or at least understand is the Fibaro Wall plug or similar. See teardown images posted in another forum for reference: 
http://www.zwaveforum.se/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=4515

Here is a similar smart plug:
https://forum.athom.com/discussion/1745/app-z-wave-neo-coolcam-z-wave-devices-main-discussion-topic/p3

Comment: Resource requests don't fit the Stack model (links go stale, books go out of print, etc).  Are you trying to figure out how they work just out of curiosity, or are you trying to replicate a similar function?

Comment: A [full wave rectifier](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_6.html) and a step down converter or linear regulator would do it...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Ron Beyer No offense but these are the vague kind of answers I try to avoid. So that’s the type of regulator that is used, or what are you saying?

Comment: It's not an answer, and the link has quite a bit of information on rectifiers. I'm saying that in all probability it has one, then the rectified voltage needs to be stepped down to 5vdc using a step down converter or (unlikely) a linear regulator. That's the "high level" theory on how to do it. If you want a detailed schematic you can try using TI's [Webench Power Supply Design Tool](http://www.ti.com/design-tools/webench-power-design/power-designer.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically cost and size are a concern when making smart outlets and dimmers so people elect to make 'hot power supply' designs (no transformer).  The two power supply chips I have seen used for this are the [MP174](https://www.monolithicpower.com/Products/Product-Detail/815/AC-DCPowerConversion/HVBuckRegulators_10W/MP174) and the [LNK306](https://www.power.com/sites/default/files/product-docs/lnk302_304-306.pdf).  They can be connected to the mains and put out around 5W.  Typically they are configured to output 12V since that is a common voltage for controlling relays.  Downstream DC-DC converters are used to make the lower voltages.

(**Important Safety Note:**  **Please** be careful when working on hot power supplies.  They are connected directly to the mains so there is **nothing** between your circuit and the mains.  To be safe, isolate your circuit with an [isolation transformer](http://www.bkprecision.com/products/power-supplies/1653A-150v-2a-ac-power-supply.html) and use a [differential probe](http://probemaster.com/4232-differential-probe-1-10-100-25-mhz-1400v/) when poking around -- at least until you know your circuit well and have it sealed up in a box).

There are a few convenient ways to make the power measurements.  Take a look at the [Kill-a-Watt](http://www.mikesmicromania.com/2013/03/kill-watt-circuit-analysis.html) circuit for a way to make power measurements with op-amps (also notice that they use a 'capacitive-dropper' as their power supply.  That is yet another way to make a low-voltage/low-power supply from mains). I have also seen people use the [Atmel chips](http://www.atmel.com/products/smart-energy/power-metering/power-metering.aspx) and the [Hiliwi chip](http://www.electrodragon.com/w/images/0/0c/DS_HLW8012_V1.3_CN.pdf) for power metering.

Everybody wants WiFi enabled outlets and dimmers these days.  Again, cost is an issue and I think the [ESP8266](http://espressif.com/en/products/hardware/esp8266ex/overview) is the cost leader right now.  If you poke around on their site you will find some smart plug reference designs that tie it all together.

Comment: You should put *much* more emphasis on just how hazardous a "hot" supply like the ones used in these circuits are.

Comment: Good point @ThreePhaseEel.  Please, Please, Please invest in an isolation transformer and a differential probe for your scope if you are going to play around with this stuff.  I actually use an [AC power supply](http://www.bkprecision.com/products/power-supplies/1653A-150v-2a-ac-power-supply.html) that limits the current so I don't get hurt when I screw up.  Well worth the purchase.

Comment: Edit that comment into your answer and I'll toss you a +1 bone for it :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image][image]
[ref](http://www.righto.com/2012/05/apple-iphone-charger-teardown-quality.html)
12V 1.3A Modem PS ref. design
http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TND330-D.PDF